# I cant read params value from req.params in restify (node JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify

I am trying to read the parameters value from **req.params** but in a different way (I am trying to make an API in **RESTIFY**).

First I read the keys that are available in **req.params**, like;

`var requestData = Object.keys(request.params);`

And than I loop through each key and try to fetch its value. below is the code;

```
for(i = 1; i < requestData.length; i++) {
             keyValue = requestData[i];
             console.log(request.params.keyValue);
        }
```

But the output shows me UNDEFINED.

**Reason:** I am trying to read the parameters this way because, then, I do not need to know the name of each parameter.

Below is the complete code:

```
var restify = require('restify');
var assert = require('assert');

var server = restify.createServer();
var client = restify.createStringClient({
    url: 'http://example.com'
});

function onRequest(request, response, next)
{
    console.log(request.params);
        var requestData = Object.keys(request.params);
        var customJsonString = '';
        var keyValue = '';

        for(i = 1; i < requestData.length; i++) {
             keyValue = requestData[i];
             console.log(request.params.keyValue);
             customJsonString += "" + requestData[i] + " : " + requestData[i] + ", ";
        }

        console.log(customJsonString);
}

function start()
{
    server.use(restify.fullResponse()).use(restify.bodyParser());
    server.get(/^\/(.*)/, onRequest);
    server.post(/^\/(.*)/, onRequest);
    server.listen(8888);

    console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

I will really appreciate any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
console.log(request.params[keyValue]);
```

`request.params.keyValue` means *Give me the value of the property `keyValue`*, whereas the code above means *Give me the value of the property whose name is stored in the variable `keyValue`*.

Also, are you sure you want to start with `i = 1`? Javascript-arrays are 0-based, so I think you want `i = 0` instead.

Comment: You are the man. It worked for me and I also understood your point. And, yes, I know javascript array starts from index 0 but I need to loop from index 1 so that I can easily skip what is on index 0 :)

Answer (score 0):

It could help if you can give us the URL you are testing right now as well as the console output your get.

However, please note that arrays in Javascript have 0 based index and your loop should look like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < requestData.length; i++) {
}
```

To loop through the properties of an object, you should probably use for..in anyway:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

I don't know if that will solve your problem but it's a start.

Comment: Code is not available live anywhere. That is why I pasted the complete code so you can play with it.

Comment: starting index is not an issue here.